# CSS: Heading Getting Cut Short

Tags: css, word-wrap

I'm getting this problem both on my iPhone and when browsing in FF at 320px wide. Notice the word 'Investment' is getting cut off:

[image: cut off]

The only styles affecting it are very basic which is making it particularly confusing, I've even tried with a different font but still no luck

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #1abae5;
    font: 1em dezen_pro_regular, open_sansregular, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: .5em 0 .25em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 2.57142857142857em; /* 36px / 14px */
}
```

Also here is a link to the page:
- http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~devkyada/about/

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I've tried the `word-wrap` property but it doesn't seem to work in the way that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a non breaking space entitiy in the HTML:

```
<h3>For us health and safety is an essential&nbsp;investment:</h3>
```

Remove it to make:

```
<h3>For us health and safety is an essential investment:</h3>
```

That should fix the problem, no need to play around with the CSS.

Comment: Good catch!  I was wondering why even the `word-wrap:break:all` wasn't working as it should...

Comment: No worries - could you set as answer please :)

Comment: worked like a treat thanks! Weird though, I could not see the non-breaking space anywhere, not even in Firebug?? But I just deleted the text and typed it out again and now it displays correctly!

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
h3{  word-break: break-all;}
```